# How to add a joomla form in frontend then add media to form data in backend?

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, joomla

I want to add a form in the front end of the
website .. then submitted data needed to display in the backend.. I want to add a media to every data that submitted. after that I want to publish selected form data with uploaded media in front end... how can I do.? Am new in Joomla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several form extensions check this link

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=forms&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1

I picked up this extension for you

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/visforms

What you have to do is. Install a free extension. Create a form for the frontend. Remember not to give access to the upload field as you are going to upload the media. There is Visforms, Chronoforms etc that can solve your purpose. You can save to database, edit your form at backend, upload and do lots of stuff.